# Why do I sometimes get little to no info about where an error occurred in Python (Jupyter)?

Tags: python, error-handling, jupyter

I am working in a jupyter notebook and have begun moving chunks of code into scripts to make it a bit cleaner. I sometimes get errors that has no info on where they occur, like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>()

NameError: name 'disp_cols' is not defined
```

Why isn't it giving me a line here? Other times it will give me information on the module that raised the exception, but not where in my code the call that returned the error was made. I've never paid attention to details of errors, I just scan the output and see if it gives me any clues where it might have happened. When there's no info I just use print statements until i find it. Is there a way to more consistently see exactly where it happened? Sometimes it gives me the surrounding code snippet, but I'm not sure why or when it chooses to give more detailed info

Answer (score 2):

I got this situation in Jupyter Notebook when I used `%%time` magic command in the beginning of the cell.

If you have any magic commands in this cell, try to remove them, it might help.